# Ошибка кнопки discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

При нажатии на кнопку пишет: **Ошибка взаимодействия**

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def tiket(ctx):

    emb = discord.Embed(title=f' Тикеты | {ctx.guild.name}',
        description = f"Для создания тикета нажмите на кнопку",
        colour = 0x88ddff
    )

    row = ActionRow(
        Button(
            style = ButtonStyle.green,
            label = 'Создать',
            custom_id = 'verif_button'
        )
    )
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, components = [row])


async def on_button_click(inter):
    res = 'Тикет создан!'
    guild = inter.guild
    if inter.component.id == "verif_button":
        
        await guild.create_text_channel(f'╰】・tiket: {inter.author.name}')
        await inter.reply(res, ephemeral = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли добавить декоратор `@Bot.event` к функции которая должна срабатывать после нажатия на кнопку